# Maximum Subarray Recursion

Tags: python

**The 'Maximum Subarray' question:**

> Given an integer array nums, find the contiguous subarray (containing
> at least one number) which has the largest sum and return its sum.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
>
> Output: 6

This should be an easy problem, but for some reason, my code runs endlessly when given a big array as input.
I hope someone can help:

**This is my code:**

```
def maxSubCaller(nums):
    return maxSub(nums, 0, len(nums)-1)
        
def maxSub(nums, i, j):
    if i == j:
        return nums[i]
    
    if j < i or i > j:
        return min(nums)
    
    sum_res = sum(nums[i:j + 1])
    left_sub = maxSub(nums, i, j-1)
    right_sub = maxSub(nums, i+1, j)

    return max(sum_res, left_sub, right_sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your implementation is actually quite time complex. For every recursive step, you are summing between two indexes. The `sum` function needs to loop through the passed parameters, and therefore your worst case time complexity is proportional to n^2, where n is the length of the input list.

This problem can be solved in linear time proportional to the length of the input list as follows:

```py
def max_sub_arr(nums):
    max_sum = nums[0]
    local_sum = nums[0]
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if (nums[i] > local_sum + nums[i]):
            local_sum = nums[i]
        else:
            local_sum += nums[i]
        max_sum = max(local_sum, max_sum)
    return max_sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(max_sub_arr([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]))
```

This is a different algorithm to yours, and only loops through the array once (doesn't use the `sum` function), and should execute faster.

There are probably further optimisations to this code, and there is no error handling (i.e. when `nums` is empty). The above should be fast enough to complete your problem however.